How to track cumulative data upload of total data to be uploaded in axios
let uploadedFiles = 0;
let fileProgress = {};
let currentSize = 0;
let fileTracker = {};
let totalFileSize = 0;
const config = {
  onUploadProgress: function (progressEvent) {
fileProgress[fileTracker.name] =
  (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total;

  currentSize = progressEvent.loaded;

 const totalSize = sizeConverter(totalFileSize);
 // sum up all file progress percentages to calculate the overall progress
 let totalPercent = fileProgress
  ? Object.values(fileProgress).reduce((sum, num) => sum + num, 0)
  : 0;
// divide the total percentage by the number of files
let percentCompleted = parseInt(
  Math.round(totalPercent / selectedFiles.length)
);
progressBar.setAttribute("value", percentCompleted);
percentDetails.firstChild.textContent = `${Math.round(
  percentCompleted
)}% uploaded`;

uploadedFilesDetails.firstChild.textContent = `${uploadedFiles} of ${selectedFiles.length} files uploaded`;
uploadedFilesDetails.lastChild.textContent = `${sizeConverter(currentSize)} of ${totalSize}     Uploaded`;} };
//generic submsion function
const submitFile = async (url, dept, files) => {
uploadedFiles = 0;
fileProgress = {};
currentSize = 0;
loadingOverlay.style.display = "flex";
const formData = new FormData();
totalFileSize = files.reduce((total, file) => total + file.size, 0);

for (let file of files) {
formData.append(`file`, file);
fileTracker = file;
try {
  const response = await axios.post(url + `${dept}`, formData, config);
  if (response.data.message == "upload successful") {
    uploadedFiles++;
    uploadedFileSize = file.size;
  }
} catch (error) {
  failDisplay();
}
}
if (uploadedFiles == files.length) {
successDisplay();
}
}; 

i am trying to display the cumulative data that has been uploaded over the total size of files to be uploaded here
uploadedFilesDetails.lastChild.textContent = ${sizeConverter(currentSize)} of ${totalSize} Uploaded; 
`my issue is when a particular file as been uplaoded the ui resartes from 0mb, since i am uploading the files one at a time, how can i prevent this from happening, doing this currentSize+=progerssEvent.loaded, only results in an ambigous value
any help would be appreciated
i got half of what i expected, but the when a file has been uploaded, the the current size starts from 0 again`
